# jQuery Validation - same rule depending on values

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm having trouble with the syntax to get 2 range values on an input field validation.

My form has 2 select fields and one text input field.

`If select1 = 1 and select2 = A`, I would like the range value on the text field to be `1 to 120`.

`If select1 = 1 and select2 = B`, I would like the range value on the text field to be `121 to 500`.

My validation code:

```
  PrepurchasePlotNumber: {
    digits: true,
    required: {
        depends: function() {
            return ($("input[name=PlotType]:checked").val() == "Prepurchase");
        }
    },
    range: {
        param: [1, 120],
        depends: function() {
            return ($("#PrepurchasePlotArea").val() == "1") && ($("#PrepurchasePlotRow").val() == "A");
        }
    },
    range: {
        param: [121, 500],
        depends: function() {
            return ($("#PrepurchasePlotArea").val() == "1") && ($("#PrepurchasePlotRow").val() == "B");
        }
    }
},
```

Digits and required work fine.
I can't get my code right to test for both range scenarios. Only one will work at any one time. 
Please can someone point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Only one will work at any one time.

Because you cannot have the same rule declared twice on the same field.  The second will likely over-ride the first.

Also, the way you've written it using the `depends`, you're saying you only want the `range` rule when the condition is met.

You simply need to use a function to `return` the parameter depending on the conditional.

```
PrepurchasePlotNumber: {
    digits: true,
    range: function() {
        if (($("#PrepurchasePlotArea").val() == "1") && ($("#PrepurchasePlotRow").val() == "A")) {
            return [1, 120]
        } else {
            return [121, 500]
        }   
    },
    ....
```

Modify logic as needed.

Comment: Thanks @Sparky. Was going round in circles having read too many threads on SO and getting my logic totally confused.